# when i use same Key, Kafka JDBC connect not publishing the messages to one Partition

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Messages which have the same Key should go to the same Partition of the topic, But Kafka JDBC source connector is publishing the message to different Partition.

I created a TOPIC(student-topic-in) with 5 partitions.

I created a student table using below script:

```sql
create TABLE student (
  std_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  std_name VARCHAR(50),
  class_name VARCHAR(50),
  father_name VARCHAR(50),
  mother_name VARCHAR(50), 
  school VARCHAR(50)
);
```

My JDBC source-quickstart properties file is  as below

```sh
query= select * from student
task.max=1
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=std_id
topic.prefix=student-topic-in
numeric.mapping=best_fit
timestamp.delay.interval.ms =10
transforms=CreateKey,ExtractKey,ConvertDate,Replace,InsertPartition,InsertTopic
transforms.CreateKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.CreateKey.fields=class_name
transforms.ExtractKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.ExtractKey.field=class_name
```

when I insert the same class student details in DB table, all messages are publishing to one partition.

```sh
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 35: {"std_id":145,"std_name":"pranavi311","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd1","mother_name":"efgh1","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 36: {"std_id":146,"std_name":"pranavi321","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd2","mother_name":"efgh2","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 37: {"std_id":147,"std_name":"pranavi331","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd3","mother_name":"efgh3","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 38: {"std_id":148,"std_name":"pranavi341","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd4","mother_name":"efgh4","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 39: {"std_id":149,"std_name":"pranavi351","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd5","mother_name":"efgh5","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 40: {"std_id":150,"std_name":"pranavi361","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd6","mother_name":"efgh6","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
```

% Reached end of topic student-topic-in [3] at offset 41

But, If I insert different class students details, still it is publishing to one partition.

```sh
student-topic-in 3 "11" @ 41: {"std_id":151,"std_name":"pranavi311","class_name":"11","father_name":"abcd1","mother_name":"efgh1","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "12" @ 42: {"std_id":152,"std_name":"pranavi321","class_name":"12","father_name":"abcd2","mother_name":"efgh2","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "13" @ 43: {"std_id":153,"std_name":"pranavi331","class_name":"13","father_name":"abcd3","mother_name":"efgh3","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "14" @ 44: {"std_id":154,"std_name":"pranavi341","class_name":"14","father_name":"abcd4","mother_name":"efgh4","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 3 "15" @ 45: {"std_id":155,"std_name":"pranavi351","class_name":"15","father_name":"abcd5","mother_name":"efgh5","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
student-topic-in 0 "16" @ 31: {"std_id":156,"std_name":"pranavi361","class_name":"16","father_name":"abcd6","mother_name":"efgh6","school_name":"CSI","partition":null,"topic":"student-topic-in"}
```

% Reached end of topic student-topic-in [3] at offset 46

I am using below command to print the details.

```sh
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t student-topic-in -f '%t %p %k @ %o: %s\n'
```

My expectation is, each class students messages should publish to one specific partition (in the JDBC connector I am assigning the Class_name as Key) But it is not working.

What exactly I am missing? how to publish each class students to a specific partition?

Comment: What key converter are you using?

Comment: i am using JSON key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter  value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case everything works properly.

If you check Kafka Connect source code, you can see in `WorkerSourceTask::sendRecords` method, that to each record before sending by Producer, Transformations are applied and then message is converted to array of bytes by `Converter`

```java
private boolean sendRecords() {
    ...
    final SourceRecord record = transformationChain.apply(preTransformRecord);
    final ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> producerRecord = convertTransformedRecord(record); 
    ...
}
```

In your case transformations are: `CreateKey,ExtractKey,ConvertDate,Replace,InsertPartition,InsertTopic` and Converter is `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`

Converter map your key with a schema to array of bytes, that is send to Kafka.

```java
@Override
public byte[] fromConnectData(String topic, Schema schema, Object value) {
    JsonNode jsonValue = enableSchemas ? convertToJsonWithEnvelope(schema, value) : convertToJsonWithoutEnvelope(schema, value);
    try {
        return serializer.serialize(topic, jsonValue);
    } catch (SerializationException e) {
        throw new DataException("Converting Kafka Connect data to byte[] failed due to serialization error: ", e);
    }
}
```

You have disabled the schema, so for your keys following invocation with results are:

- 11 `serializer.serialize(topic,new TextNode("11"))` = [34,49,49,34]
- 12 `serializer.serialize(topic,new TextNode("12"))` = [34,49,50,34]
- 13 `serializer.serialize(topic,new TextNode("13"))` = [34,49,51,34]
- 14 `serializer.serialize(topic,new TextNode("14"))` = [34,49,52,34]
- 15 `serializer.serialize(topic,new TextNode("15"))` = [34,49,53,34]
- 16 `serializer.serialize(topic,new TextNode("16"))` = [34,49,54,34]

Each message is send by `Producer` to some partition.
To which partition message will be send depends on `Partitioner` (`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner`). Kafka Connect uses default one -  `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`

Under the hood `DefaultPartitioner` uses following function to calculate partition: `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;`

If you apply to your parameters (5 partitions and, arrays of bytes of your keys), you will get as follow:

- `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(new byte[]{34,49,49,34})) % 5` = 3
- `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(new byte[]{34,49,50,34})) % 5` = 3
- `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(new byte[]{34,49,51,34})) % 5` = 3
- `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(new byte[]{34,49,52,34})) % 5` = 3
- `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(new byte[]{34,49,53,34})) % 5` = 3
- `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(new byte[]{34,49,54,34})) % 5` = 0

Hope, that more or less explain, what and why

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by using String converter `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`